# How do I navigate an interview when the interviewer is late?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism

I am currently interviewing for a position. I was asked to either join a virtual interview room or call for an audio only experience. I joined the interview room ten minutes early and when my scheduled time came by, the interviewer did not join. I tried calling the phone line, thinking it could attract the interviewers' attention to no avail. At the 15 minute mark, I emailed the recruiter, and have gotten no reply. I'm currently at the 30 minute mark of my interview, and no one has shown. I am personally worried about what would be proper and/professional for me to do in this situation. I doubt that the interviewer would ditch my appointment for no reason, but I considered that maybe they had double-booked their time and that there was something I could do in terms of that. My next step is to try calling the recruiter, but I don't know what else I can do. Any advice?

Edit: 50 minutes in, I have confirmed that I had the time correct, and that the Hiring Manager confirmed my appointment.

Comment: You've done all you could do. But don't jump to conclusions about their "professionalism". For all you know, there was a mix up, or someone died or something. Wait and see what they tell you. If it's their fault, will they apologize? In either case, continue applying to other companies, while you wait for this one to get back to you.

Comment: If this was pre-Covid, and you were interviewing in person, it'd be possible that they were being *deliberately* late as a way of measuring your reaction to being insulted.

Comment: @nick012000 Has this happened to you before? It's a very strange theory.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Pretty sure that there's been questions about that sort of thing on this SE site before. See this question: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/157572/company-is-playing-psychological-mind-games-with-interviewees-is-this-ethical/157620#157620

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do nothing. You followed the instructions. You joined the call, you dialed the phone number. You've emailed the recruiter. Stay calm, take a break, and work with the recruiter to reschedule the interview later.

These things happen. The interviewer hit problems or was held up. Or forgot about the interview. In any case this is not something that's in your control, and not something that reflects on you in any way.